# buildkite error : The plugins file is missing or invalid. Cannot find module 'xlsx' when running cypress test . Runs fine on local

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress, buildkite

I am getting error when running the cypress test on buildkite as below:

Status: Downloaded newer image for cypress/included:6.1.0

[2022-01-31T10:32:13Z] Your `pluginsFile` is set to `/e2e/cypress/plugins/index.js`, but either the file is missing, it contains a syntax error, or threw an error when required. The `pluginsFile` must be a `.js`, `.ts`, or `.coffee` file.

Or you might have renamed the extension of your `pluginsFile`. If that's the case, restart the test runner.

Please fix this, or set `pluginsFile` to `false` if a plugins file is not necessary for your project.

Error: Cannot find module 'xlsx'
Require stack:

- /e2e/cypress/plugins/read-xlsx.js
- /e2e/cypress/plugins/index.js

the same test runs fine on local on both browser and headless

"xlsx" is present in the package.json as both dependencies and dev dependencies.

code inside read-xlsx

```js
const XLSX = require("xlsx");
const fs = require("fs");

const read = ({file, sheet}) => {
  const buf = fs.readFileSync(file);
  const workbook = XLSX.read(buf, { type: 'buffer' });
  const rows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet]);
  return rows
}
 
module.exports = {
  read
}
```

Someone please help

Comment: How have you set up the code inside the `read-xlsx.js` file?

Comment: ``` const XLSX = require("xlsx");
const fs = require("fs");

const read = ({file, sheet}) => {
    const buf = fs.readFileSync(file);
    const workbook = XLSX.read(buf, { type: 'buffer' });
    const rows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet]);
    return rows
 }
 
 module.exports = {
    read
 } ```

Comment: i have pasted the code in the original question also. Thanks 
jjhelguero

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
But in my case, was an issue with case sensitive.
I put 'XLSX' inside the require in the read-xlsx.js file.

My read-xlsx.js file became like this and worked:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const XLSX = require('xlsx')
```